# When a function missing the return value, the compiler generates a warning but not an error?

Tags: c++, function, xcode5

Here is a c++ function:

```
int FuncWithoutReturn()
{
  int var = 10;
  ++var;
  // No return value here !!!
}
```

In MSVC, compiler generates error:

> error C4716: 'FuncWithoutReturn' : must return a value.

But in XCode 5, the compiler just spits a warning:

> Control reaches end of non-void function

In runtime if I am lucky, the app crashes. I know it is a stupid error but it would be good that the compiler yields an error in first place.

Just wondering anyone knows WHY XCode think it is a warning instead of an error.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but Is there any case that missing return value is on purpose? I mean I my case, that def an error. But since the compiler thinks the error is a warning by default. I think there must be a reason, WHY...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `-Werror=return-type` to make that warning and error, in my original comment I forgot that. You can see it [live](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/def6595bfbd6af3a).

This is both an option in [clang](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/UsersManual.html#options-to-control-error-and-warning-messages) and [gcc](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Warning-Options.html), as far as I understand `XCode` can use either one.

Falling off the end of value returning function is [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior), we can see this by going to the [draft C++ standard](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2012/n3485.pdf) section `6.6.3` *The return statement* paragraph *2* which says:

> [...]Flowing off the end of a function is equivalent to a return with no value; this results in undefined behavior in a value-returning function.

Undefined Behavior does not require a diagnostic(*warning or error*), although in many cases compilers will provide one.

Comment: Standard, yes, that is what I want to know. Thanks.

Comment: Actually I'd still like to know why the people writing the standard think it's better this way.

Comment: We all want to know :)

Answer (score 3):

You can enable it using `-Werror=return-type`

> Just wondering anyone knows WHY XCode think it is a warning instead of an error.

Check your project's/target's/xcconfig's settings for "Mismatched Return Type" (aka `GCC_WARN_ABOUT_RETURN_TYPE`).