# Garbage value being displayed

Tags: c++, class, oop, object

I was learning about classes and I stumbled upon this while practicing. I am confused over as to why am I getting the garbage output for `amount` and the same goes for why is the correct value of `amount` being displayed beforehand.

Where am I going wrong?

I have pasted the output.

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Resort{
    float charges  ;
    int days ;
    float amount ;
    float compute() ;
public:
    void getdata();
    void disp();
};

void Resort::getdata(){
    cout<<"\nCharges : ";
    cin>>charges ;
    cout<<"\nNo of days : ";
    cin>>days ;
}

void Resort::disp(){
    cout<<"\nCharges : "<<charges
        <<"\nDays : "<<days
        <<"\nAmount : "<<compute()<<endl ;
}

float Resort::compute(){
    amount = (days*charges) ;
    cout<<amount;
}

int main(){
    Resort obj ;
    obj.getdata();
    cout<<"\n\n";
    obj.disp();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Turn on/up your compiler's warning level.

Comment: Please compile with all warnings and debug info (e.g. `g+++ -Wall -g`) and learn how to **use the debugger**

Comment: I enabled -Wall on the compiler settings. Was that the one you were talking about @BasileStarynkevitch ?

Comment: Did you also use the debugger?

Comment: I haven't used it until now but I am learning how to do that right now :)

Answer (score 0):

You aren't returning anything from the `compute` function, but you are outputting its return value in `disp`
.

You probably want something like:

```
float Resort::compute(){
   amount = (days*charges) ;
   cout<<amount;
   return amount;
}
```

Comment: It solved the problem but why was my compiler not showing an error? And value being displayed beforehand ? I am using codeblocks.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6260917/why-there-is-no-compiler-error-when-return-statement-is-not-present

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the garbage values in the variables you can define a *constructor* for the Resort class and provide the *default values* to the variables so that even if you forget to process the values of the variables then too the value initialized by you you would be displayed rather then the garbage value.
eg 
you can include a constructor like this in the class definition .

```
  public:
    Resort()
    {
      charges = (float)0.0 ;
      days = 0;
      amount = (float)0.0;
    }
```

And specifically for the above code you need to call the compute function before calling the function for printing the values.

Answer (score 0):

In `disp` you try to print the return value of `compute`, but you have forgotten to add a return value there. You also get double printouts because `compute` prints to `cout` as well.

A tip for the future is to always have as many compiler warning flags turned on as possible (for `g++` this is `-Wall`). Doing this would probably have had your compiler warn you of the omitted return value in `compute`.